# Multiple instances of Visual Studio on development PC

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Is it possible to open two instances of Visual Studio on the same development PC? i.e. run a long running program on one version and continue working on something else (including debugging) in the other.

I have looked into changing port numbers, but apparently this is done in the machine.config and there is one per PC.

Comment: Two or more instances of Visual Studio are perfectly normal. I often have that situation. If you have a problem then you have not described it well.

Comment: @Dialecticus, I cannot debug both instances of Visual Studio at the same time.  That is the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I debug several projects at the same time without problems. Maybe you want to debug the same project? That is no "two instances of VS" but "two instances of the same project". Maybe you want something else, but I assure you that two Visual Studios can debug two projects at the same time.

Comment: @Dialecticus,  thanks.  It is two versions of the same projects.  Debugging one stops debugging the other.

Answer (score -1):

We usually start debugging with `F5` key, `Debug > Start Debugging` menu item, but it starts only a single instance of the "StartUp Project". If you would have several projects in the solution you'd see that only one of them can be a "StartUp Project" (written in bold in solution explorer).

But there is one more way. Right-click on a project, then `Debug > Start new instance`. This way you can start as many processes as you'd like. It takes a little time to get used to debug more than one instance at the time and "Process" drop-down list in "Debug Location" toolbar can help you determine in which process you are currently debug-stepping.

Comment: The point of downvoting is to improve the answer, but how can I improve it if I don't know why the answer is being downvoted?